# How to determine calling object and passed arguement objects while overloading an operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was learning operator overloading on C++.
I was wondering how do we exactly determine object at which side of the operator is calling the operator overloaded method and what side of objects gets passed as an argument.

For an example, below code accepts an `int` and returns an `int` which is a commonly known knowledge.

```
int operator=(const int a) {
        foo(a);
        int x = a;
        return a;
    }
```

But the **binary + operator** can be overloaded in two ways

***Code 1***

```
ReturnType operator+(T a) {
        T x;
        foo(a);
        x = this -> a + a;
        return x;
    }
```

**Or**

***Code 2***

```
ReturnType operator+(T a, T b) {
        T x;
        foo(a);
        x = b + a;
        return x;
    }
```

Now when we call `JohnDoe = John + Doe`, `John + Doe` produces the `ReturnType` from the code. And a `John` could become the calling object and `Doe` could become the passed argument calling ***Code 1*** **or** `John` and `Doe` both could become the passed arguments calling ***Code 2***.

So how do we decide which way from the above two, to implement the operator overloading?

The `+` operator is just an example. I want to understand the general way operator overloading works. How is it decides that which side of the operator will call the method, which side of the object will be passed to the argument and which side of the operator will be the second argument.

I did find a good reference to all the operators overloaded. But it didn't help me understanding the general terminology that I want to understand.
http://www.drbio.cornell.edu/pl47/programming/TICPP-2nd-ed-Vol-one-html/Chapter12.html

Comment: You didn't mention a pretty important ingredient: Code 1 is only for *member overload*, and in that case the left-hand-side is `*this`.  Code 2 is only for *non-member overload* and in that case the left-hand-side is `a`.

Comment: Specifically see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421729#4421729) for deciding whether to use member or non-member

Comment: Sorry, just cropped up an example to explain my doubt. Didn't craft it well. Also a newbie in the C++ world. Just learning. Can you suggest the right edits please?

Comment: Ok. Will refer the link for the whole understanding. Thanks a lot for the info.